# javascript merge 2 arrays with undefined elements

Tags: javascript

Hello I need a little help with js i have 2 arrays

```
const a = ['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5']
const b = ['link11','link22',undefined,'link44',undefined]
```

how can I replace the elements of a with b with ignoring the undefined index so the output would be

```
a = ['link11','link22','link3','link44','link5']
```

I tried to do it like this

```
  Array.prototype.splice.apply(
    a,
    [0, b.length].concat(b)
  );
```

but I got the array b back

Comment: What have you tried? Please share the attempted code. Data in `b` array is wrong.

Comment: i updated my question with what i have tried

Comment: Please share the valid value of array `b`.

Comment: sorry just noticed i updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over array `a` using `array#map` and then extract the values from array `b` based on the index value. For `undefined` value, we can use the value in array `a`.

```js
const a = ['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5'],
      b = ['link11','link22',undefined,'link44',undefined],
      result = a.map((link,i) => b[i] || link);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = ['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5']
const b = ['link11','link22',undefined,'link44',undefined]

const supplanted = b.map((e,i)=>e??a[i]);
console.log(supplanted);
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

```
const a = ['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5']
const b = ['link11','link22',undefined,'link44',undefined]

var c = a.concat(b)
// ["link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5", "link11", "link22", undefined, "link44", //undefined] 

c = [...new Set(c)] // to get the distinct elements
// ["link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5", "link11", "link22", undefined, "link44"]

c = c.filter( Boolean ) // to remove undefined
// ["link1", "link2", "link3", "link4", "link5", "link11", "link22", "link44"]
```